# Exporting Google Bookmarks to Kifi

Tags: bookmarks, google-bookmarks

I would like to export my Google Bookmarks in to Kifi. Unfortunately, Kifi doesn't have such an option. However, they do allow imports from Pocket, Delicious, Kippit, Instapaper or Pinboard. However, none of these appear to have a method of importing bookmarks from Google Bookmarks. How can I transfer my data over?

Answer (score 3):

Just pushed an initial Google Bookmarks import support. Export your Google Bookmarks (to a `GoogleBookmarks.html` file), and import that with [Kifi](https://www.kifi.com)'s importer.

Several bookmark services use a fairly certain standard for tags/labels/collections, which we support. Unfortunately, Google Bookmarks does it a bit different and duplicates links for every "label".

In short, right now, labels won't auto-tag in Kifi for now, but the links should come in just fine. I'll add label support to the roadmap and hopefully we can add it soon.

If you have any problems, send a message to Kifi support, and I'll make sure you get everything in.